# Close div only when cursor is further away then 200px from the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to close a popup DIV when a user clicks with his cursor on the outside of the popup DIV. I use this JQuery to do so:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
          var container = $(".polnamen");

          if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
              && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
          {
              container.hide(200);
          }
      });
```

This code works fine, however I only want the DIV to close when the cursor is **further away then 200px** from my DIV. Is this possible, and how should I do this?

Comment: I suggest you use a timespan is stead of a position. If the user is x time off the container, close it. Calculating the position is going to  be very costly because of the constant processing required to calculate the mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you..

First find the distance of mouse cursor from element and if we find it 200px away then we need to fire our

```
var mX, mY, distance;    
$element  = $('#element');

function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) 
{
       return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
}

$(document).mousemove(function(e) 
{  
    mX = e.pageX;
    mY = e.pageY;
    distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);

    if(distance == 200)
    {
        // Start : Write your action here --------------- //
        var container = $(".polnamen");

      if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
      {
          container.hide(200);
      }
     // End : Write your action here --------------- // 
   }         
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, I think you have to wrap your div in another div which is 400px larger, and check if the click is in the new div.

The HTML will be :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="polnamen">
        <!-- Your code here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS :

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    left: -200px;
}
```

The jQuery :

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
          var container = $(".wrapper");

          if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
              && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
          {
              container.hide(200);
          }
      });
```

Comment: I don't think this would be an option for me since the reason I don't want people to click next to it is because I have a google Pie chart there on wich users can select slices, using a bigger DIV will prevent users to click another slice

Comment: Yes, it's right my solution is quite inappropriate to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the click relative to the document from the [`pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [`pageY`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) event properties when you receive the click.

You can get the position (relative to the document) and dimensions of the `div` from the jQuery [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) *(confusingly, it's `offset` not `position`)*, [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/), and [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) functions.

Then a bit of math tells you whether the click is far enough away.

Comment: without jQuery, you can use the `element.getBoundingClientRect()` method to quickly find the div's location in relation to the body. it returns a `clientRect` object with the following format `{top:xx, left:xx, right:xx, bottom:xx, height:xx, width:xx}`